# Hacer un webview de una pagina que aún no está publicada

Tags: php, html, android, app, webview

He creado una pagina web que incluye código *php*, *javascript*, *html* y *css*, y ahora quiero hacer un **webView** de esta página.

El problema está en que mi página aún no está publicada, y por lo tanto solo está en mi ordenador. ¿Hay alguna posibilidad de hacer el **webview** de esa página que aún no está publicada?

He probado sustituyendo el localhost por la IP de mi ordenador, pero no funciona, me da el siguiente error:

```
webpage could not be loaded because of net:: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED
```

También he probado colocando la url de una página ya publicada y sí funciona, pero es que preferiría no publicar la página web hasta que la *app* esté también terminada. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

El código por si sirve de algo es el siguiente:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var webPagina=findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webpagina)
        webPagina.clearCache(true)
        webPagina.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
        webPagina.loadUrl("https://192.168.1.47/Registro/login.php")
    }
}
```

PD: ahora cargo el código desde assets pero no carga el código php.
Este es el código que esta cargando:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, email, password, nombre FROM usuarios WHERE id=:id');
    $records->bindParam('id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $user=null;
    if(count($results)>0){
        $user=$results;
    }
}
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="registro2.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bienvenido</title>
        <?php require 'partials/headeregistro.php' ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div">
        <h1 id="unete">Unete a Crapping</h1>
        <header>
        <div id="crapping">
        <a href="indexregistro.php">Crapping</a>
        </div>
        </header>
    
        <?php if(!empty($user)):?>
        <br>Hola <?= $user ['email']; ?>
        <br>Estás dentro.
        <a href="logout.php">Cerrar sesion</a>
        <?php else: ?>
        <h1 id="ini">Inicia sesión o registrate</h1>
        <span id="inien">
        <a href="Login.php" >Inicia sesión</a>
        </span>
        <span id="regisen">
        <a href="Entrar2.php" >Registrate</a>
        </span>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Podrias intentar poner los archivos de la pagina web en la carpeta assets y cargar el html index desde el webview.

Comment: @Osdward Muchísimas gracias. Eso era lo que buscaba. Pero tengo una pregunta: ¿Puedo poner código php en la carpeta php y que se cargue en el webview?

Comment: El webview carga un html , si en el html hay código js, o php en teoría debería funcionar, hazlo y me dices.

Comment: @Osdward Si llamo al archivo indexregistro.php lo único que muestra es el código escrito. Y si lo llamo indexregistro.html el códgio html si lo interpreta pero el php no y lo escribe como antes. Te dejo el código que esta cargando en la publicación por si te es útil. ¿El que llame a una base de datos mysql es un problema? Gracias por tu atención.

Comment: @Osdward el código php nunca jamás va a funcionar en un webview cargado desde los recursos de la app... porque la app no es un web server y php necesita ser interpretado por un web server y traducido a html para que el webview pueda verlo. Webview solo es un cliente, no va a hacer cosas de servidor... Es como intentar abrir un .php directamente en chrome, no sirve de nada. Un cliente es un cliente, un servidor es un servidor. Si quieres que tu app renderice un webview desde assets debe ser estático o al menos JS, es decir, estar hecho con lenguajes de cliente.

Comment: Copiaste la carpeta de la pagina web a la carpeta assets de android y llamaste al archivo desde la carpeta assets?

Comment: Prueba usar en la url http en lugar de https: `"http://localhost/Registro/login.php"`

Comment: @Sal Lo he portado y tampoco. Me da el mismo error, pero gracias

Comment: @Benito-B ¿Entonces no hay ninguna forma de hacerlo? Aunque sea de otro modo. ¿Otra solución? Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Osdward Si, eso hice.

Comment: @D1618 Haz las cosas bien, aloja la página en un servidor web (incluso puedes usar tu propio PC para hacerlo, con XAMPP requiere dos minutos...).

Answer (score 0):

Si obtienes el error:

> webpage could not be loaded because of net:: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

Esto indica que no tienes acceso a la página.

**si tu página se encuentra en tu PC y tu dispositivo se encuentra en la misma red una opción es publicar tu página usando el IIS**, abre el IIS Manager y configura el directorio para publicar tu página

[Abre IIS Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525920(v=vs.90))

[Cómo crear un sitio web con IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/topic/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-sitio-web-con-iis-y-windows-7-c441e1ad-d8af-46ad-13d2-cd2d7d687c30)

[Crear un nuevo sitio web en Windows IIS 10](https://www.ssl.com/es/c%C3%B3mo/crear-nuevo-sitio-web-iis-10/)

1. Abra el Administrador de IIS.
   Abre Gerente de Servicios de Información de Internet (IIS). Puede encontrarlo rápidamente escribiendo "IIS" en el campo de búsqueda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Añadir sitio web.
   Expanda el directorio de su computadora haciendo clic en el > a la izquierda del icono en el panel de la izquierda. Luego, haga clic derecho Sitios y seleccionar Añadir sitio web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Crear nombre del sitio.
   El Añadir sitio web La ventana se abrirá. Primero, agregue un nombre fácil de recordar para el sitio web en el Nombre del sitio campo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Añadir ruta física.
   Navegue hasta el directorio que contiene los archivos de su sitio web para que aparezca en el Camino fisico campo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5. Establecer opciones de encuadernación.
   Debajo Encuadernación, Haga click en el botón Tipo (HTTP o HTTPS), Dirección IP, Puertoy Nombre de host.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

6. Decide si iniciar o no el sitio web.
   Si desea iniciar el sitio web de inmediato, asegúrese de que Inicie el sitio web de inmediato está chequeado. Si no, desactívelo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Termina.
Haga clic en el OK botón para terminar de crear su nuevo sitio web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Otra opción es simplemente definir una url que puedas acceder temporalmente, posteriormente cuando este publicada tu página simplemente la reemplazas.

```
//webPagina.loadUrl("https://192.168.1.47/Registro/login.php")
webPagina.loadUrl("https://es.stackoverflow.com/")
```